# creating SQL script

Tags: oracle, shell

I'm trying to create an SQL script to automatize inserting of values into a table.

I have a table table1 with 2 columns: key, value.

I want to insert a few rows:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (key, value) VALUES ("tomato1","random_value_1")
INSERT INTO table1 (key, value) VALUES ("tomato2","random_value_2")
INSERT INTO table1 (key, value) VALUES ("tomato3","random_value_3")
INSERT INTO table1 (key, value) VALUES ("tomato4","random_value_4")
```

How can I put this into a shell script that I can execute from command line.

Thanks

Comment: is it php? Saying this for the dollar symbols

Comment: @Sebas ah no; its oracle; I just made up some values

Comment: Are you asking how to create a script of 1000 inserts or how to run such a script ?

Comment: a script with 5 entries will do; I can adapt it. The OS is unix, hence it's called a shell script ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

save as a file with .sql extension.

then run from the command line with a sql connection tool like SQLPLus  (you don't indicate which database you are on)

Comment: adding this comment for answer completion (by A. B. Cade): put the insert statements in a file (filename.sql) and then run it from your script like this: sqlplus <user>/<password>@<db> @filename.sql

Answer (score 2):

You should also combine inserts to the same table into one, as it is much faster, like so:

```
INSERT INTO table1 
(key, value) VALUES 
("tomato1","$1"),
("tomato2","$2"),
("tomato3","$3"),
("tomato4","$4")
```

Comment: The difference in execution time is pretty big. You can easily fix them using find/replace techniques.(replace insert into ... with nothing and just manually add the first one in the beginning, and replace new lines with ,\n so everything is seperated with a comma.)