# About .sql files and more details on it

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

What is .sql file?
How to create a .sql file?
How to view a .sql file?
Can we convert .txt file to .sql file?
How to create a .sql file using notepad else with any other software?
All the above questions are with respect to Oracle 10g database Express Edition...

Comment: Can be similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11107391/creating-sql-script).

Answer (score 1):

Usually, a .sql file is just a text file with SQL queries or PL/SQL blocks or maybe SQL*Plus scripts.

So, yes, you can just edit those in Notepad (if you have no better text editor).

Comment: How do you want to create it? If you know SQL, you can use Notepad. If not, we need more details.

Comment: I am creating a file using ed first.sql.. Then after the notepad prompts i am typing all the procedure then while saving it is asking me to name it again.. so now i had stored that file at my desktop naming "first.sql" is this the .sql i have created or just with the extension i required..

Answer (score 0):

A file with the .sql extension is just to help the reader to know that the file contains SQL. Other than that, a .sql file is the same as .txt. You can save somefile.txt as somefile.sql.